# Simple math not returning expected value in java?

Tags: java, math

I'm just making a temperature converter as one of the first small projects I'm writing myself. I'm unsure what I'm doing that's leading to this error but when I run my program, 74 degrees F gets converted to 9.144 degrees celcius, which my formula shouldn't be returning. Anybody got any ideas what I've done here that's giving me this issue?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What's the tempurature outside?");


    double tempF = input.nextInt();

        if (tempF < 45.00) {

            System.out.println(tempF + " degrees? Oh it's a little chilly out there");
        } else {

            System.out.println("Unless it's raining, sounds like a beautiful day!");
        }

    System.out.println("We use a bit of an outdated measurement system over here stubborn as we are. Let's convert that to a measurement you're more familiar with");

     double tempC;
     
     tempC = ((tempF * 0.556) - 32.00);

     System.out.println(tempF + " degrees fahrenheit here in the States should feel like " + tempC + " Celsius back home. Give or take some humidity depending on where that is exactly :)");
     

   
    }
}
```

I've tried messing with the formula a few times but keep getting the same result. It should be converting to about 23.3 degrees C, and I'm very confused where the 9.144 keeps coming from

Comment: Well, what's (74 * 0.556) - 32? That looks like 9.144 to me... so I'm unsurprised by the result. You should look more carefully at the conversion formula you're meant to be implementing... (Hint: subtracting 32 *after* the multiplication is very different from subtracting 32 *before* the multiplication...)

Comment: This is not a Java or a programming problem ─ if you calculate `(74 * 0.556) - 32.00` then you will see that 9.144 is the correct result. If you want 23.3 to be the result then you need to do a different calculation.

Comment: The correct formula should be `tempC = (tempF - 32) * 5/9;`

Comment: You input nextInt. You might consider nextDouble. Also consider `System.out.printf("%0.2f°C%n", tempC);`

Comment: That is correct, stepping away from the computer for a bit I can't believe i didn't realize this

Answer (score 2):

The formula to convert Fahrenheit to Celcius is not correct in your code.

You are using below formula:

```
tempC = ((tempF * 0.556) - 32.00);
```

But it should be:

```
tempC = (tempF - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
```

Updating the formula should fix the issue.

Comment: worked like a charm, of course it had to be something so simple. thank you kind stranger